# Which distributed strategy should I use when running training without GPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, distributed-computing

There are many distributed strategy in Tensorflow,

- MirroredStrategy
- TPUStrategy
- MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy
- CentralStorageStrategy
- ParameterServerStrategy
- OneDeviceStrategy

Some of them run on one machine and broadcast model to different GPUs, and some of them use different GPUs on different machines.

My question if I don't have GPU in my server, which strategy should I use, so I can get the benefit when running distributed training?

I try to run **MirroredStrategy**, **ParameterServerStrategy** on four machines, but it seems that it's slower than running on a single machine.